# Google Apps Script error 'Bad Request' when transferring a .xlsm-file to a GSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, email-attachments, xlsm

I have an Excel-File (.xlsm) as a Gmail-attachment in my inbox and want to transmit it to GDrive. There it should be saved as a GSheet. I am trying to automatize this process using Apps Script.

Unfortunately, I get an error starting the Script. **(API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request)** It's very strange because a few times the script works and the file could be converted without any problems. Last week, it worked as soon as I forwarded the Mail with the attachment to someone (Don't ask me where's the context). But now, it's all history and I don't know how to fix the error.

I am new on StackOverflow and I am really looking forward to every answer from you. Thank you very much.

Here's the code:

```
function importFunction() {

  var threads =  GmailApp.search('CC520_Report_Lukas_GAS_ABC');                             
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();    
  var message = messages[0];                                                                
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];                                            

  var resource = {
    title: 'NewFileLukas',                                
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id: 'xxxxx6BD1SIfI0Cz5bmGahzSlHUxxxxxx'}], 
};

var insert = Drive.Files.insert(resource, attachment);      // Here comes the error.
```

Comment: Can you add the line `Logger.log(message.getSubject());` and then identify the email with the subject from the Gmail UI. Have a look at the attachment to see what is the difference between the attachments that can be converted and then ones that can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert a `.xlsm` file to Google Spreadsheet.
- `attachment` you are using is the `.xlsm` file.
- In your situation, an error of `API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Bad Request` occurs at `Drive.Files.insert(resource, attachment)`.

  - You want to remove this error.

For this, how about this answer? I had also experienced the same issue.

#### Modification points:

- The mimeType of the `.xlsm` file is `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12`. In your script, when `console.log(attachment.getContentType())` is used, if `attachment` is the `.xlsm` file, such mimeType is returned.
- When `importFormats` is confirmed with the method of "About: get" in Drive API [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?hl=en&apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22importFormats%22%7D), it seems that `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12` can be converted to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. This can be seen at Drive API v2 and v3.

  - But, when `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12` data is used to `Drive.Files.insert(resource, attachment)`, an error occurs. In this case, I confirmed that even when I tested this using Drive API v3, the same issue occurred.
  - I thought that this conversion might have not been reflected yet. Also I believe that this will be modified at the future update.

So as the current workaround, I would like to propose to convert the `.xlsm` file to Google Spreadsheet by changing the mimeType of the blob.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
```

To:

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0].setContentType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
```

or

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
if (attachment.getContentType() == "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12") {
  attachment.setContentType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
}
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I could confirm that by changing the mimeType to `MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL`, the `.xlsm` file could be converted to Google Spreadsheet.
- In this case, the macro of the `.xlsm` file is not converted to Google Apps Script. And also, after the `.xlsm` file was converted to Google Spreadsheet, when the Google Spreadsheet is converted to the excel file, the macro is not included. I think that this is the specification. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [setContentType(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentType(String))